# Exporting VCD which can only be read on an old VCD player

Tags: video, dvd, rca, vcd

I have an old VCD (2001) which can only be played on a particular VCD player - something like the first image below.

- This VCD player can only be connected to a TV, not a computer.
- I would like to extract out the video inside to a computer for safekeeping.

I've tried using another DVD/VCD player which can be connected to a computer via USB (I'm using Macbook Pro), and using those to try extracting the video via [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/).

However, the VCD takes extremely long to read and my computer hangs after some time. I've tried various VCD readers and software but the same problem persists.

My last resort is to take the VCD to a professional recovery firm to recover the video. But I would like to try other means first.

How can I extract the video, which can only be played using the old VCD player with RCA connector?

[image: Old VCD Player]

[image: DVD reader with USB port]

Comment: You should include in your question the make and model of your VCD player and the file properties of the file you want to digitize. Also, you might be able to send the signal out of the VCD player to a capture device but without knowing the model its hard to say.

Comment: Maybe something like that would help? https://www.amazon.com/Plug-Composite-S-Video-Capture-Adapter/dp/B01GN8FBF6

Comment: "which can only be played using the old VCD player with RCA connector?" This is nonsense, vcd's have been playing on Windows PC's for many years. The disc is going bad.